# Add CSS rules to Pelican without creating a theme

Tags: python, css, static-site, pelican

I rather like the default Pelican theme `notmyidea`. It serves my purposes nicely.

However, in order to implement the Python-Markdown `admonishments` extension, I need to add a few css rules to the template.

Nothing I can find in the documentation (or through googling) seems to explain how to do this. Only how to create a brand new theme, or use a custom style sheet, which overrides the default style sheet.

Is there a way to add a supplementary style sheet or even just a few supplementary rules?

Comment: Will the rules be used for every page on your site or maybe just a few?

Comment: I'd like for every page. The syntax `!!! <type>\n<The content of the warning>` is a Markdown syntax for note boxes and warnings. It produces a `<div class="admonishment <type>"></div>` tag. I'd like to be able to use it in any post. It's just a blog. As lightweight as I can make it.

Comment: Alternatively, if I can just find the directory containing the `notmyidea` theme already installed and modify the css files _there_, I'd be fine with that dirty hack.

Comment: It's in the python packages directory (`site-packages/pelican/themes/notmyidea/`)… but that would break your changes when you update Pelican.

Comment: Then that hack is useless :-/ Thanks, though. I guess I could copy that theme from the packages directory and point to the static copy instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pelican allows for [theme inheritance](http://docs.getpelican.com/en/3.6.3/themes.html#inheritance) since version 3, but it seems to work only with the `simple` theme for some reason…

Here are some less or more hacky ways, still without editing the theme itself:

- You can include HTML in Markdown, so just inserting `<link rel="stylesheet"  href="…">` or even `<style>…</style>` in page/article `.md` files would work. You can get the `Makefile` to do it automatically for every page/article. It won't break on updates and the notmyidea theme would get updated with Pelican instead of staying an old static copy.
- Notmyidea [includes a CSS file](https://github.com/getpelican/pelican/blob/95ff3b8e628ba483de345b838de7c0052b2f3b02/pelican/themes/notmyidea/templates/base.html#L9) specified in [`CSS_FILE`](http://docs.getpelican.com/en/stable/settings.html#SOCIAL_WIDGET_NAME) settings variable to allow you to use the wide variant (`CSS_FILE = "wide.css"` in the docs). Looking at the [wide.css source](https://github.com/getpelican/pelican/blob/95ff3b8e628ba483de345b838de7c0052b2f3b02/pelican/themes/notmyidea/static/css/wide.css#L1), it imports `main.css`. So, you can create eg. `custom.css`, import notmyidea's `main.css` (like the `wide.css` does), and add your custom rules. And then point `CSS_FILE` to your `custom.css`.

Comment: I really like your first suggestion. When I open the Makefile, I am a little unsure as to how to implement it. It looks like Bash and yaml. Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Pelican does not provide theme inheritance--unless you're using the built-in 'simple' theme.

You can *override* a theme's templates using [THEME_TEMPLATES_OVERRIDES](https://docs.getpelican.com/en/stable/settings.html?highlight=theme_templates_overrides#themes), but there's no theme inheritance (including no templates or style inheritance) in Pelican. Yet. This is a killer feature of WordPress, in my opinion.

Also, this feature has an [open feature request right now](https://github.com/getpelican/pelican/issues/1092).